# seleniumAddress not taking effect in Protractor config

Tags: selenium, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I am having a issue where `seleniumAddress` is not taking effect in protractor config. I use `seleniumAddress: 'http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub'` but I see:

`[18:52:35] E/launcher - Timed out waiting for the WebDriver server at http://127.0.0.1:47780/hub`

The port should be `4444` instead of `47780`. Any ideas?

`one@development ~/github/drop $ protractor --version
Version 4.0.7`

Comment: You are using a version of firefox that is not supported by selenium used within protractor. Check the version of selenium and downgrade to the supported version of firefox and run test again

Comment: When you start your spec, it should tell you the server it's using.  i.e. `Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub`.  You can also visit either of the Urls you posted above, and see if it takes you to the webdriver sessions page.